# GreaseMonkey is not processing my button click

Tags: greasemonkey

I want to get GreaseMonkey to process a button click. The HTML for the button is generated in a perl CGI which is accessed by GM_xmlhttprequest. The javascript to handle the click is in my user script.

Here is the user script. It prepends a div to the top of a webpage and populates that div with what comes from my CGI via AJAX.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        button test
// @namespace   http://www.webmonkey.com
// @description test that I can intercept a button and process click with AJAX
// @include     http*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

function processButton() {
    alert("got to processButton");
}

var myDiv;

var details = GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: 'GET',
    url:"http://localhost/cgi-bin/buttonTest",
    onload: function (response) {
        myDiv = document.createElement('div');
        myDiv.id = 'mydiv';
        myDiv.style.border = '4px solid #000';
        myDiv.innerHTML = response.responseText;
        document.body.insertBefore(myDiv, document.body.firstChild);
    }
});
```

Here's my CGI.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                                                                                          

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print qq|<button onclick="processButton()">Click here</button>| ;
```

When I load a web page I get a new div with the HTML button code in it as I expect. When I click the button nothing happens. No alert. I created an HTML example to make sure I wasn't doing something really stupid. The example works fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function processButton() {
    alert("got to processButton");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="processButton()">Click here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

There's a console error message:

```
ReferenceError: processButton is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I should add that I need for the javascript button handler function to be seen by GreaseMonkey since I'll be calling GM_xmlhttprequest inside that function. Otherwise, I'd just put the function in the CGI code.

Comment: I suspect that there is some sandboxing going on that keeps the javascript that's defined inside of GM from being seen by the HTML being loaded via AJAX but I'm still not sure what to do.

Comment: If I declare the processButton function in my CGI and then put this in my userScript then my code works:

unsafeWindow.processButton = function() {
    alert("hijacked processButton");
}

Is this the right way to do this or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

If I declare the processButton function in the HTML code that includes the button declaration and then put this in my userScript then my code works:

```
unsafeWindow.processButton = function() { 
    alert("hijacked processButton"); 
}
```

In other words, I'm now able to hijack the button from GM.